# Restaurar una tabla truncada alojada en un proveedor externo

Tags: mysql, sql

Realice un `truncate table` sobre una tabla equivocada y necesito recuperar todos sus datos (mysql).

El asunto es que esta base de datos esta en un cluster en digital ocean, por ende no tengo acceso a consola de comandos.

Comment: La edición anterior fue rechazada por dos usuarios porque no mejora la pregunta. Además, ¿podrías indicar lo que has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: ¿Revisaste en las documentaciones de DO si hay info relacionada?

Comment: Trate de restaurar las tablas con los archivos log que se crean, pero el problema es que al servidor solo tengo acceso a la linea de comando de mysql, ya que no es un servidor en si, sino un cluster de digital ocean.